# Laravel validation if fails return POST method instead of GET

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I access a page of `Route::post('search')`. From this page, I perform a form submission using a POST method. If the validation fails, I get error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` probably because when Laravel validation redirects back to the same page, it redirects as a GET method.

I am unable to change nor add a new Route for search due to strict rules here. How should I redirect back to search page as POST method?

This is from CustomFormRequest.php

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
  \Log::debug("WAS HERE");
  \Log::debug(print_r($this->request->all(), true));
  \Log::debug(print_r($this->request->method(), true));
}
```

I can see the request but not the method. Meaning I cant update the method manually to try and check if this would work. Though if I check the value in controller without the formrequest, I can see both.

I tried searching for SO questions but nothing really about my concern.

How should I redirect to the same route using POST method?

Comment: Why the search method using POST though? I have yet to see a good reason for this excluding the fact that, it is just a big inconvenience for a user.

Comment: The previous programmer used a form tag to perform search function. That is why the route for the search is POST method.

Comment: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` has nothing to do with the validation layer, that error is on the routing layer. You have declared a post route, but are making a get request to that route.

Comment: `probably because when Laravel validation redirects back to the same page, it redirects as a GET method.` so you are using a `POST` request to load the page?

Comment: `so you are using a **POST** request to load the page` Yes I am accessing the `search` page using a `post` method. from here, perform a `post` form submission

Comment: it is not possible to redirect as `POST`. Your best bet is to redirect to another route and trigger some js client side that makes the `POST` request.

Comment: as I thought... I will try this suggestion or other ways possible.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to get around this:

1. Add another get route to the same controller action.
2. Allow get and post on the same route:

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    // ...
});
```

3. Use get instead of post, even if a form is used:

```html
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Like my question above, I am unable to change the method to get since it will append the query to the URL, which the client does not want. That is why I am stuck on using POST route as is. If I add match get/post, when it redirects, the previously searched information will be cleared since again the searched values are not in the URL.

Comment: Normally, this would be the correct answer but not in my case